# What is the best Handbrake preset for playing video files on Tivo Series 3

Tags: video, conversion, encoding, handbrake, tivo

I have Mac2Tivo app running, and I can put video files on Tivo. Tivo supposedly supports avi and various other encoding, but half the time video's don't play. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with encoding options. So the question is, what is a good Handbrake preset to use for viewing stuff on Tivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it looks like the trick is selecting AAC (faac) sound option instead of AC3 Passtrhough. Other than that I'm using MPEG4 format (with .m4v extension for filenames) at 80% quality.

Comment: Just a quick mention that this method works with Tivo Desktop (win7) as well.

Answer (score 0):

From http://code.google.com/p/streambaby/wiki/video_compatibility

> **Handbrake encoding H.264 mpeg4 with AC3 audio for Tivo (from mpeg2
>   source)**
>
> *(Thanks to txporter for contributing this one)*
>
> If you are encoding from an mpeg2 source with AC3 audio the following
>   encoding profile using handbrake works very nicely:
>
> ```
> handbrakeCLI -i inputFile.mpg -f mp4 -O -e x264 -b 5000 -a 1 -E ac3 -x ref=3:mixed-refs=1:bframes=3:b-pyramid=1:weightb=1:analyse=all:8x8dct=1:me=umh:subq=9:psy-rd=1,0.2:direct=auto:keyint=24:min-keyint=2:no-fast-pskip=1:no-dct-decimate=1 -v -o outputFile.mp4
> ```
>
> NOTE: In the above you can adjust video bit rate (-b 5000) to be
>   higher or lower depending on quality desired, for example using -b
>   2000 for SD sources.

or

> **Handbrake encoding H.264 mpeg4 with AC3 audio for
>   Tivo from DVD source**
>
> *(Again thanks to txporter for contributing this one)*
>
> ```
> HandBrakeCLI -i "path_to_VIDEO_TS" -t 1 -f mp4 -O -e x264 -b 5000 -2 -T -a 1 -E ac3 -s 4 -F -x ref=2:bframes=2:me=umh --strict-anamorphic -v -o outputFile.mp4
> ```