# What settings should I use in Elgato Turbo.264 HD for conversion for streaming to Tivo?

Tags: macos, video, tivo

I saw this question that is asking the same thing, but using Handbrake settings: [What is the best Handbrake preset for playing video files on Tivo Series 3](https://superuser.com/questions/69120/what-is-the-best-handbrake-preset-for-playing-video-files-on-tivo-series-3).  I'm wanting to do the same thing but with the Elgato software and hardware combo.

One answer to the above question points readers to http://code.google.com/p/streambaby/wiki/video_compatibility, which I've looked at but of which I can't make correlations to the Elgato software controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a bit and reading the documentation more closely, I believe the "Apple TV" preset will do the trick.  And it seems to be working fine when I send the output file to my Tivo.

The docs say that the Apple TV preset will apply these settings:

Video: H.264 Main Profile, 5 Mbps max., 1280×720 pixels at 24 fps max. or 960×540 pixels at 30 fps max.
Audio: AAC-LC, stereo, 160 Kbps, 48 kHz

That will work fine for what I'm doing - converting video that was at standard definition for play on my Tivo HD.